# maximum call stack size exceeded in my reactjs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am a beginner in react.js, I am trying to implement a simple fizzbuzz example. Overall, I think I got the gist of how react and its components work, but when I try to run this code on codepen, I get this error:

> maximum call stack size exceeded

Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value : '',
    number: 0
  };
  this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this);
  this.handleDecrement = this.handleDecrement.bind(this);
  this.fizzBuzz = this.fizzBuzz.bind(this);
}

fizzBuzz(nb){
  if(nb % 15 == 0 && nb!= 0) 
    this.setState({value : `FizzBuzz `});
  else if(nb % 5 == 0 && nb!= 0) 
    this.setState({value : `Buzz `});
  else if(nb % 3 == 0 && nb!= 0)
    this.setState({value : `Fizz `});
  else  
    this.setState({value : ''});
}

handleIncrement() {
  let nb = this.state.number + 1;
  this.setState({number: nb});
  this.fizzBuzz(nb);
}
handleDecrement() {
  let nb =  this.state.number-1;
    if(nb >= 0) 
      { this.setState({number: nb}); 
        this.fizzBuzz(nb); 
      } 
    else 
    {
      this.setState({number: 0});
    }
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {this.state.number} </h1>
      <h1> {this.state.value} </h1>
      <input type="button" value="add" onClick={this.handleIncrement()} />
      <input type="button" value="sub" onClick={this.handleDecrement()} />
    </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

anyone could point out what mistake i did please ? it's been puzzling me for the last two hours.

best regards

Comment: `this.handleIncrement()` should be `this.handleIncrement`, I think you're constantly rerending the component because of this

Comment: Don't call `this.handleIncrement()` and `this.handleDecrement()` in the `render` method.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean about not calling this.handleIncrement() and this.handleDecrement() ?? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You are *calling* `this.handleIncrement()` and assigning the *return value* to `onClick`. But `this.handleIncrement()` doesn't return anything. I assume you want to bind `this.handleIncrement` as event handler itself. As such you have to assign *it* to `onClick`, not *its return value*, i.e. don't call the function, pass it.

Comment: YES !! that was the mistake i made @FelixKling, also, thank you so much, now i understand what passing a function and passing its return is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick={this.handleIncrement()}` means the function `handleIncrement` is immediately evaluated and its return value is assigned to `onClick`.

However, `handleIncrement` updates the component's state by calling `this.setState({number: nb})`. Every time a component's state is updated, the component is re-rendered. So, in your case, you get a chain of calls `render -> handleIncrement -> render -> handleIncrement ...` and so on, hence your error (maximum call stack size exceeded).

You don't want the `onIncrement` method to be evaluated immediately inside the `render` function. Rather you want it to be evaluated in case of an `onClick` event. Therefore, you need to pass a reference to the function `handleIncrement` to your `onClick` prop.

So, your code should be

```
<div type="button" value="add" onClick={this.handleIncrement} />
```

and similar for `handleDecrement`.